# New UI of Facebook Developer dont have API key

Tags: facebook

I have around 800 FB apps created. FB UI was throwing the "FB error" every time. Now a days it seems that the FB has changed the UI and this UI dont have the API key.

How can i get this API key for newly created  FB app?

Comment: in here? https://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Applications Don't need API Key, use the new php sdk 3.0.1 and check out their documentations, you just need App ID and App API Secret.